# Google Tag Manager is returning undefined from Google Analytics Legacy Client ID that exists

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on a website for a client that uses Google Analytics Classic. They are not upgrading at this time. They are using Google Tag Manager and want me to get the client ID from Google Analytics Classic through GTM (which I have been able to accomplish) and then send that to analytics using GTM. I have it so that it fires a tag when it detects that ID, but when I go to send that ID using a variable I created it returns undefined 95%.

The Tag that gets fired is my SendToAnalytics. It is Classic Google Analytics tag type. It is triggered by WindowLoadedWithValidID which fires when my variable CheckForClientID code does not return false. The code for variable CheckForClientID is:

```
    function() {

        var getClientId = function () {
            try {
                ga(function (tracker) {
                    if (tracker != undefined) {
                         var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
                         return clientId;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                if (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
      getClientId();
    }
```

My tag SendToAnalytics is where I am having the issue. It is a page view track type and it creates a custom variable to send to GA. The value of that variable is returning undefined 95% of the time. I have tried numerous ways to get that value. I have used code that is similar to the above, I have used:

```
function(){

 var clientID = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
 return clientID;

}
```

and anything else I can think of. It almost always returns undefined even though it is firing after the other trigger fires which depends on the GA script being loaded.

I know that the GA code is asynchronous, but once this tag fires  it is because the GA script has already loaded otherwise it would continue to return false. The variable that returns undefined is confusing me because it shouldn't initialize until after this tag has been fired and therefore the GA script should have already been loaded, or is that wrong? Does GTM initialize the variable as soon it sees that the tag exists whether or not it has been fired yet? If that is the case, how would I get the value of that variable to return the clientID and not undefined?

Comment: Your inner function returns only when there is no id or in case of exceptions. The outer function returns nothing at all, so rhe bigger mistery is why this would work in 5% of cases.

Comment: I asked the question after numerous attempts to get the code to do what I was hoping it would. The code I wrote was my attempt to revert it back to what worked the best. I forgot to put the return statement. I fixed it for the question just now, but the code after still does not work as a variable. It triggers the tag, but the tag doesn't get the variable as I would have hoped. It return undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments says, not sure why your function is actually working, if the account is really a legacy account the following function must do nothing.

> function(){
>
> var clientID = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');  return clientID;
>
> }

What you have to do now:

1.- Read the cookie and get the second value
I created the following variable:
[image]

2.- create a custom JS, this read the cookie for the first time (the fastest way), them if this is not available read the tracker element , and them if everything fails to create a Google Analytics object and get the client id, replace the UA on that script, this case will happen only on the first page of a new user. This avoids hit without client id.

```
function(){
    var cookie_utma= {{cookie - utma}};
    if(typeof cookie_utma != "undefined"){
      return cookie_utma.split(".")[1];
    }
    if(typeof _gat != "undefined")
    {
       return _gat._getTrackerByName()._visitCode();
    } 
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']); //change with you UA to avoid issues 
      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
  return _gat._getTrackerByName()._visitCode();
}
```

Comment: I wrote the question after numerous different code attempts. The code I used for the question was me attempting to revert it back to what I recalled working the best. I forgot the return statement. Regarding the following code not working if it is a legacy account - if I change the return to a console.log I get the account number a portion of the time, usually after I refresh the preview mode in GTM. I just did it again in developer tools and it worked as well. It always works in dev tools, nut only sometimes in the code.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it returns the Google Analytics account. I am attempting to get the client ID that google uses to track the user.

Comment: Hey! sorry I mix both ids (account & client), I've updated the code to retrieve the client id, also it can be read via the cookie __utma . but it can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I did find one typo in the code however that makes the code not work as intended. In your first party cookie you have the name of the cookie as "_utma" but it should actually be "__utma" with 2 underscores. You helped me a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: Oh yes, I'll update it,  the screenshot is wrong but my tags is ok, i should deteled it when i the pess imp. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using the following code for my variable that the tag is using to send to Google Analytics.

```
function(){
window.getCookie = function (cname) {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    cstart = document.cookie.indexOf(cname + "=");
    if (cstart != -1) {
      cstart = cstart + cname.length + 1;
      cend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cstart);
      if (cend == -1) {
        cend = document.cookie.length;
      }
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cstart, cend));
      }
  }
  return 'not-available';
}


var GAuserID = getCookie('__utma');
var userId = GAuserID.split('.');
var clientId = userId[1] + '.' + userId[2];
return clientId;
}
```

Comment: This solution works for what I needed, but @Kemen has an answer better suited to GTM so I marked it as the correct answer.